# Restarting a the run() of thread

Tags: android, multithreading

I am building an app that moves an object over the screen and you can control it's direction with buttons. I want that when I click on the button it will react right away. The problem is that if you click when it already has started the while in the run() of the Thread it will first move the object were it was supposed to be before the click and only then it will react to the click.

So I thought that if there is a way that on click it will stop the run() function right away and restart it, maybe by restarting the thread.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

In Java a thread can not be restarted. You can however loop what the thread does.

Also, interrupting any code immediately is not possible and would be very dangerous if possible.
So you must design your code to check often if it needs to cancel execution, possibly signaled by `Thread.interrupted()`.

From what I understood about your actual problem, you don't need to restart `run()`.
Guessing from the little information you gave us, I recommend to have a look at [Animators](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html).

Another option is to permanently move the object and set the velocity (x and y) per second. Therefore you wouldn't need to restart, but only change these variables.

If you need more information or I misunderstood your question, please comment.